# I want to secure my mysql connection and php page

Tags: php, mysql, security

I want security against hackers for my mysql connection in a php page.

I have database user's password different from the root password. And I've used this query:

```
function make_safe2($safe) 
{
$safe = strip_tags(mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['bname'] . $_POST['why'] . $_POST['email'] . $_POST['submit'])));
return $safe; 
}
```

Is there any more ways by which I can assure security against SQL injections and other hacking methods. I don't have any login page. I have a form with bname, why and email fields and a submit button. Does submit button needs escape string? :P Silly question I guess.

A complete syntax for other ways of preventions from SQL injections and other methods will be appreciated. :)

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Please. I always repeat to USE the SEARCH FUNCTION!

Answer (score 2):

You should use prepared statements with binded parameters.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);

$code = 'DEU';
$language = 'Bavarian';
$official = "F";
$percent = 11.2;

/* execute prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

[See the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/679449) is a complete guide to understanding how to prevent against SQL injection.

Comment: Let me go through it. :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If I use this syntax:
    $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('My SQL Query goes here right?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

what is 's' and $name here?

Comment: `s` indicates a string, `$name` refers to a variable.